# new Date() produce a date that doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using a code to produce continuous dates for a schedule, but one of the dates produced from this code does not exist (31/9/2022). Is there a way to prevent this?

```
var Sheet = ss.getSheetByName('list');
var Range = Sheet.getDataRange();
var Values = Range.getValues();
var Row = Values.length;

const year = 2022           //input year of first date
let month = 9               //input month of first date    
let day = 5                 //input day of first date

for (let i=0; i<Row-1; i++){
    var date = new Date(year, month, day+i)
    var fulldate = [date.getDate(), date.getMonth(), date.getFullYear()].join('/');
    console.log(fulldate)
    Values[1+i][0] = fulldate
    Range.setValues(Values)
}
```

Comment: Are you aware that the month parameter is 0-based? (So 1 is februari, not januari.)

Comment: JavaScript will not throw an error. It tried to fix your invalid dates. If you want validation on Dates, you need to code something up.

Answer (score 1):

date.getMonth() function returns values from 0 to 11;

so if it returns 9 the month is October

learn more here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp